# HTML not being rendered by Vue

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

So, currently I am studying Vue.js and I have ran into an error, please let me know what I have done wrong. I understand I might be blind to a simple error, but sometimes you need another set of eyes.

**app-home.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Vue-Practice</title>
        <link href="./app-home.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
        <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="vue-container">
            <p>{{ test }}</p>
        </div>
    <script src="./app-home.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**app-home.js:**

```
const body = document.querySelector('body');

body.onload = () => {

    import Vue from 'vue';

    new Vue({
        el: '#vue-container',
        data: {
            test: 'this is a test element'
        }
    });

};`
```

page output: `{{ test }}`

```
console error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in app-home.js:1
```

Comment: Well for one you're not mounting your vue instance: `new Vue(...).mount()`. Don't know about that error, though.

Comment: 1) You can't import modules like that in the browser environment. 2) Imports are top-level and always come before regular code. See https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/installation.html#CDN for browser instructions

Comment: Supposedly the error means you have a `<` somewhere in the first line of your app-home.js script that is not part of valid syntax, though the code you've included doesn't have anything like that.